# Switch current UIVIewController on stack

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have my root view (A) and a view I present modally (B). On B I want to display a new view (C) to replace B on the stack, that way when I call removeModalViewController or whatever it goes back to A.

So the stack first looks like this `A->B`

Then in B, a tap of a button changes the stack to `A->C`

How would I do this? I've tried a million different things with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix, just tell B to `dismissModalViewController` with `animated` = `NO`. Right when you do this, present C as a modal view controller, also not animated.

Comment: I've been trying that. In B's source I call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO]` but it just hangs there

Comment: That's not normal behavior. How do you present B?

Comment: `[self presentModalViewController:[[BViewController alloc] init] animated: YES];` this is called in the root, A

Comment: That is correct, although you should probably be keeping a reference to B instead of creating it inside the `present` method. Your problem here isn't the technique you're using, it must be some other aspect of your setup.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll play around with it some more. Thank you

Comment: Try using storyboard, it makes things easier.